# The Truth probability

Tags: probability

It is believed that the opponent in the discussion can not be more than 90% wrong ...
And that you yourself can never be more than 90% right ...

What is the minimum percentage probability of truth (or lack thereof) in the discussions?

Thanks

Comment: this is not clear.  Do I and my opponent exhaust the available options?  That is, does knowing that my opponent is, say, $50\%$ wrong convey any information about my rightness?

Comment: Just to say:  this does not appear to have anything to do with probability.  You haven't given us any information at all about any probabilities.

Comment: Thanks, this question was asked me today, so im trying to figure ou

Comment: I think you want a word like "ratio" or "concentration" instead of "probability", but I just can't find one that sounds right. Perhaps "proportion"?

Comment: Yes, I agree the 'ratio' is a better term in this question.

Comment: Reading casually, one might be tempted to say:  the least possible truth amount would be $10\%$ for my opponent and $0\%$ for me, but that might not be what is intended.  If we have taken opposite sides of a binary point then we can not both be wrong.

Answer (score 1):

Fun question. I assume what is meant is:

- *At most* $90\%$ of your opponent's statements are false.
  (Thus, *at least* $10\%$ are true.)
- *At most* $90\%$ of your statements are true.

Also, every statement is either true or false, and not both. And you both make approximately the same number of statements.
Then: what is the minimum possible percentage of true statements and maximum possible percentage of true statements?

The minimum percentage is when $0\%$ of your statements are true and $10\%$ of your opponent's are true. In this case, overall, only $5$ percent of all statements are true.

The maximum percentage is when $90\%$ of your statements are true and $100\%$ of your opponent's are true. In this case, overall, $95$ percent of all statements are true.

So we have between $5$ and $95$ percent of statements are true. The wide range is due to the fact that both of your requirements were relatively loose requirements, and only bounded the number of true or false statements on one side.

**Addendum.** If we don't assume that you and your opponent make the same number of statements, then the minimum is $0$ percent and the maximum is $100$ percent. The minimum is when only you talk, and you only make false statements. The maximum is when only your opponent talks, and she only makes true statements.

Comment: Great! As expected!